# Making a wav file from a list of numbers in Mathematica

Tags: export, sound

I have a list of numbers from a simulation of acoustic pressure generated by a virtual musical instrument by another program (Comsol multiphysics). I would like to "hear" the tone produced by different settings in the virtual instrument.

How can I do this? In particular, can I convert the data into a .wav file?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of your data? Or give a link to where it can be found.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 17):

In *Mathematica* it is easy to turn any time series data into sound. Here are the Boston temperatures for a few decades:

```
data = WeatherData["Boston", "MeanTemperature", {{1970}, {2012}, "Day"}];
DateListLogPlot[data, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0], AspectRatio -> 1/5]
```

[image]

To turn it into sound and play it in a *Mathematica* notebook:

```
ListPlay[data[[All, 2]], SampleRate -> 2000]
```

[image]

To export to .wav file:

```
Export["test.wav", %]
```

Comment: +1 Very nice example! I personally like the sound of the RiemannZeta function.

Comment: @Matariki Thanks! I am not sure about sampling rate for RiemannZeta and other details. Will your code fit in a comment?

Comment: Its rather simple. I got it years back I think it was a Mathematica example. `Play[RiemannSiegelZ[2000 t], {t, 0, 5}, PlayRange -> {-20, 20}]`